# Jmeter-groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Interger for class

Tags: groovy

I added the below code in script of JSR223 PostProcessor

```
int counter = Interger.parseInt(vars.get("counter")) + 2 ;
vars.put("counter", Interger.toString(counter));
```

Then it shows error in log as the following

```
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Interger for class: Script17
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:89) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:45) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:955) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:573) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Interger for class: Script17
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:65) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:51) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:341) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at Script17.run(Script17.groovy:1) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
```

What is wrong? Could you help me?

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure you've just misspelt Integer